# running error when calling a c library function from assmbly code

Tags: c++, c, debugging, assembly, linker

I was trying to develop a better understanding of the linkers and how they work, so I tried to call the simple function(printf) from the c library (MSVCRTD.lib) but with assembly code on MASM.

I dissected the external symbols from the "MSVCRTD.lib" library which has many printf's functions like:

```
__imp__printf
_printf
___imp___printf_l
;and more ...
```

I had 2 challenges (linking/building) and (running).

as for the first challenge linking my assembly code to the library was not  a problem at all, I could link my assembly code  with any call to any external function of the library,all I needed just to mimic the decorated (Mangled) name of the function so the linker can recognize it. I first tried the second one "_printf" which locked shorter and nicer, and after disassembling it's code I knew that it takes 2 parameters on the stack and it's a cdecl calling convention, so I write the code it needs and it was:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
option casemap :none
Extern printf :PROC    ; MASM will decorate it to be "_printf"

.data
message byte "Hello C library, this is MASM calling"

.code
main proc
push 0
push offset message
call printf
add esp,8 ; clean the stack
retn
main endp
end
```

and shoot! every thing was smooth .

[image]

but when I tried the same thing with **"_imp__printf"** the **problems** start.

BTY: this function is the one that the c compiler calls when you write the famous hello world! c application

the linker successfully build the program but when I run the program it crashes!

I read the linker output messages and every thing looks normal except for the line that says:  " Discarded _printf from MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)".

I debugged the program with OllyDBG and I found that the call instruction that should land on the function actually lands on an area that is recognized as DATA ! in the .rdata section

[image]

**why the *"_printf"* function succeed and the *"__imp__printf"* didn't  :(  , any idias?**

Comment: That is a pointer, make sure you have written `call [_imp__printf]`.

Comment: Still data :(  just the value of it changed, when write call _imp__printf the jmp go to adress 0F617EE0 and with call [_imp__printf] the jmp goes to 50367EE0

Comment: Umm listen, I followed the address that the jmp instruction landed on, which has the data(51A67EE0) - the first line in OLLYDBG picture - and you were right, it is a valid address!, not only a valid address but surprisingly it's the address of _printf  function ! - the function that worked - ,but jumping to a pointer didn't resolve it.  so I guess may be _imp__printf  do nothing but a jump to the _printf . the problem here is that the import address table may be did not built correctly so the jump goes to the correct address. if you need any details about the situation just tell me.

Comment: I'm sorry,  "_imp__printf" will never be a jmp instruction as I told you in my last comment , because I forgot that the object file inside the library  is a MSVCR100D.dll which means it's an import library object not a real object, so the _imp__printf will never be a real instruction, but it's the information the linker needs to build the import address table, and that is why the import table didn't built successfully . I strongly think the problem happened because of something related to the linker when it tried to build the imports function table, my guess will be  the section information.

Comment: You misdeclared `_imp__printf`. It is a `DWORD` not a `PROC`.

Comment: @Raymond Chen so why `_printf` worked this way and `_imp__printf` didn't

Comment: `_printf` is a `PROC`. `_imp__printf` is a `DWORD`. You declared `_printf` correctly, so it worked. You declared `_imp__printf` incorrectly, so it didn't work.

Comment: @Raymond Chen thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks, it did work... please tell me how did you know that _imp__printf is a Dword and _printf is a proc ???

Comment: Because Jester said so in the first comment. You want to do a call indirect, which means that the thing you are calling is not a procedure. It is a pointer to a procedure.

Comment: @Raymond Chen I did the call indirect by `call [_imp__printf]` but it didn't work . it worked only when I declared `_imp__printf' as `DWORD` even without the [  ] , it looks like when I do a jump to  an address declared as data the assembler will produce the ob code to make an indirect jump automatically even without the [  ] in my source code , Is that correct ?

Comment: If the square brackets and the declaration conflict, the assembler chooses the declaration. It sounds like you need to get more experience with the assembler before trying to do fancy stuff like this.

Comment: @RaymondChen thank you , yes I do need experience. computer is not my field and I want to learn it. thanks for your help . there is one more thing that will make it crystal clear for me.  why there are too much "printf's" with too many decorations in the C library??? , and when I used `Dumpbin` , it looks like they all from one member(import library)  in the library(.LIB) that has the only one `_printf` function that is a real function not a pointer like the others decorated "printf's" . can you please tell me why all of those decorated "printf's"

Comment: I would recommend that if you are new to programming, you start with something easier than assembly.

Comment: @Raymond Chen I started 2 years ago with vb.net, but I had too much questions about HOW these things being done at the low level of computer , then I decided to read the books listed in the Cambridge University CS school syllabus. and I think assembly is much easier and simple than the high level aspects , it's straight foreword and now when I read some high level code, I get a better understanding and better vision about how is this high level code being done at the low level. thanks for your help :) . can you please tell me why there are too many decorated "ptintf's" in the C library ?

Comment: I cannot explain it in 140 characters or less.

Comment: @RaymondChen . sorry, I just didn't want to bother you with another question.   Here it is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245535/why-there-are-too-many-decorated-mangiled-versions-from-the-same-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Mr. Jester and Mr. Raymond Chen
they provided the solution for the problem in the comments.

it was the declaration of the `__imp__printf`. that is declared as a PROC like the working example `_printf` but there were DATA so declaring.

```
Extern _imp__printf :DWORD
```

will makes it work as `printf`

thank you so much , both of you

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this is not the solution , but I will leave it for later reference. the solution in the next answer.

I think I'm close to figure out why calling `_imp__printf` external function failed because of a problem in the jumping instruction, here is what I did..

I tried to build the hello world! C program to see how the `_imp__printf` function will look like in the symbols table if the file compiled as a C program instead of assembly , I then dumped the OBJ file that was compiled from both calling program (the MASM/ and the c ),  and the results were very interesting , here is the `_imp__printf` in the OBJ compiled from the **C file**

[image]

and here is the `_imp__printf` in the OBJ compiled from the **MASM file**

[image]

Interesting! and after referencing to the COFF documentation It seems that the relocation type REL32 will force the linker not to process the import address table correctly so the jump instruction will fall as it happened before.

**now my question is "how I can tell MASM to assemble the file with `_imp__printf` symbol type "DIR32" ?**