# Multiple decorated/mangled versions from the same function in a single library

Tags: c, visual-c++, dll, linker

When you dump the external symbols of a library, you may find there are multiple versions of the same function name; such as the case with `printf` function from the C library, you will find names like

```
__imp__printf
_printf
___imp___printf_l
```

Why there is no just one version of the function?

When I tried to see which OBJ member in the library they are belong to, I found that they all belong to the same OBJ file (an import library) that have only one version, which is `_printf`, and this is the only `PROC` name among all these versions, and the rest of them are "DATA".

The library is MSVCRTD.lib and the library  member is MSVCR100D.dll, the platform is Microsoft Windows 7 and Visual C++.

Can anyone explain this to me?

**EDIT:**  adding most of the "printf's" in the msvcrtd.lib library my eye could catch, and actually there is more.

some of them belong to the same OBJ member in the library( according to it's offset number in the pictures), and some are not . I need to understand why all of these versions of printf's exist in the c library ? are they exist to support several compilers(with several mangling) that might call the printf function? because when I called printf from MASM it decorated it to be `_printf` and when I called it from C compiler , it decorated it to be `__imp__printf` , so I guessed these multiple versions might exist to support different compilers that might use the library, Is that correct or not?

please I need to understand the linkers and how they work , and an answer to this question will help me a lot. for us there is only one printf that is we call all the time, why the linker needs all of these?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: `printf` and `printf_l` are two completely different functions, meaning that `___imp___printf_l` has no business being in your list here. As for `_printf` and `__imp__printf`... I'd guess that the former is a static symbol, while the latter is a dynamic library symbol. I don't know though why you see both in your library. What library are you inspecting, BTW? What platform?

Comment: As @AnT noted, `printf_l` is a different function entirely, so it doesn't belong on the list. `__imp__printf` is the import table entry. It gets filled in with the address of the `printf` function when it is determined at runtime. `_printf` is a stub function that calls through the import table entry. (You can disassemble it to see.) This is just part of the normal way that Windows manages imported functions.

Comment: @RaymondChen  I added most of the printf's in the library so you can get what I mean better . for us there is only one printf , that is printf("hello world!), why the linker needs all of those ?

Comment: @AnT sir I added most of the symbols in the library it's a microsoft  library msvcrtd.lib

Comment: There are many functions in C that have the letters `p` `r` `i` `n` `t` `f` in their name. You are seeing the other ones. They have nothing to do with `printf` aside from having a similar name. it's like asking "When I look in the phone book, I see `Bob Smith`, `Robert Smith`, `Robert Smythe` - why are there so many names for the same person?" Answer: It's not the same person.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks, but I mean why they are EXIST in the library? as long as the only exported function we can call is `printf` ?

Comment: They are features of the library. Lots of books exist in the library, even the ones you never read.